# css interpret html time-object

Tags: css, object, time

is css capable of interpreting html time-objects?
More specific: would it be possible to define display-rules for time-objects containing a past-date?

My website offers a gig-list for a band. Since the list is quite long, it would be helpfull to "grey-out" all past performances.

this one would be grey ....

```
<time datetime="2018-09-08">
    08.09.2018: Last night of the proms - Royal Albert Hall - Starttime: 20:00
</time>
```

this one is still ... ehh blue!

```
<time datetime="2018-12-31">
    31.12.2018: The Blitz Party - Village Underground - Starttime: 22:00
</time>
```

Comment: No, you should use javascript because css has no time-detection capability and it doesn't have comparison operator like "less o greater than"

Answer (score -1):

Check this out. JS Fiddle preview at https://jsfiddle.net/itsselvam/8z5kja7w/

```css
time{display:block; clear:both; margin:10px;}

time[datetime="2018-09-08"] {border:1px solid grey; color:grey; padding:4px; border-radius:4px}

time[datetime="2018-12-31"] {border:1px solid blue; color:blue; padding:4px; border-radius:4px}
```

```html
<time datetime="2018-09-08">
    08.09.2018: Last night of the proms - Royal Albert Hall - Starttime: 20:00
</time>

<time datetime="2018-12-31">
    31.12.2018: The Blitz Party - Village Underground - Starttime: 22:00
</time>
```

Comment: You just grayed out manually a past date because you know what's the current date. Op asks instead if css can detect a past date

Comment: Got you! in your above question you never mentioned this has to be dynamic. If you need a dynamically grey all the past date, you need to use JS to validate and then apply the CSS based on JS result.

Comment: Hi, thanks 4 trying!
As fcaleran pointed out, I'm looking for an automated solution that passes css-classes to given time-objects. 
Could php-be of help? >> read object, set classes accordingly?
Greetz,
Arthur